# Testing goodness of fit of kernel density estimates. Matlab

Tags: matlab, kernel, histogram, curve-fitting

I wonder if there is a way for testing the goodness of fit for a kernel density estimate after using `ksdensity`, so I can pick the better kernel function: `epanechnikov` or `normal` or another?

Comment: What goodness of fit metrics are you interested in? Kolmogorov–Smirnov, Chi-squared, R-square, Adjusted R-square, Root mean squared error (RMSE)? Note that GOF does not necessarily mean you are using a good model to describe your data generating process https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162757

Comment: I have some experience with [`chi2gof`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html) (Chi-squared) and [`kstest`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html) (Kolmogorov-Smirnov). Generally, Kolmogorov-Smirnov is a good starting place, but you should not use it if you're estimating parameters from the data (i.e., your hypothesized CDF is obtained by fitting). This is a [fundamental limitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test#Test_with_estimated_parameters) and [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html#inputarg_CDF) states it too.